# Java 8 Generic of Generic for Monad Transformer

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, java-8, monad-transformers

I'm using "totally lazy" and I have a desire for `Either<String,Option<A>>` in a program I'm writing.  This is a terrific place to use a Monad Transformer for Option (similar to the awesome one that exists in Scalaz 7).  I can't seem to get the Generics right in Java 8.  The code below is what I would love for it to look like (for a start).  Any suggestions of how to get it to work/compile would be AMAZING!!!  Please help me get this Monad Transformer to exist for my Java 8 code.

```
import com.googlecode.totallylazy.Monad;
import com.googlecode.totallylazy.Option;
import com.googlecode.totallylazy.functions.Function1;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

public class OptionT<M extends Monad,A> {
   final M<Option<A>> run;

   public OptionT(final M<Option<A>> run){
       this.run = checkNotNull(run);
   }

   public <B> OptionT<M,B> map(Function1<A,B> f){
       return new OptionT<M,B>(run.map(o-> o.map(f)));
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** I get the following compiler failure:

```
OptionT.java:15: error: unexpected type
    final M<A> run;
          ^
  required: class
  found:    type parameter M
  where M is a type-variable:
    M extends Monad<Option<?>> declared in class OptionT
OptionT.java:17: error: unexpected type
    public OptionT(final M<A> run){
                         ^
  required: class
  found:    type parameter M
  where M is a type-variable:
    M extends Monad<Option<?>> declared in class OptionT
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: You can't pass generic params to a generic param in Java (`M<?>`, where M is a generic). This won't translate directly from Scala; they're significantly different languages.

Comment: Java's type system does not support higher-kinded types.  You can't do this.

Comment: Is there a way to "work around" this limitation? Something like `<M extends Monad<Option<A>>,A>` ?  I tried something like this but couldn't guarantee `M` remains the same in the type signature for `map`.  :(

Comment: My guess is that whatever you come up with will be ugly and verbose to the point of not being useful (as compared to doing it not-monadically). Java just isn't designed for this highly functional style of coding. It can do the simple stuff decently (mapping, basic transformations, etc), but when you get into the type-system aspects of FP (monads, currying, etc) it starts to look more and more like object-oriented programming, which is what it really is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [cyclops-monad-api](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-streams), there is a introductory [blog post that you might find helpful here](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/introducing-the-cyclops-monad-api-a7a6b7967f4d). I am the author of the library and blog post.

I've posted a working implementation of your example (for JDK 8 Optional) below -

```
public class OptionT<A> {
   @Getter
   final AnyM<Optional<A>> run;

   public OptionT(final AnyM<Optional<A>> run){
       this.run = run;
   }

   public <B> OptionT<B> map(Function<A,B> f){
       return new OptionT<B>(run.map(o-> o.map(f)));
   }


}

@Test
public void test() {
    OptionT<Integer> optionT = new OptionT<>(AnyM.ofMonad(Stream.of(Optional.of(10))));
    System.out.println(optionT.map(num->"hello world"+num).getRun().asSequence().firstValue());
}
```

Will print out

```
Optional[hello world10]
```

AnyM wraps any Monad type. Java doesn't support Higher-Kinded-Types, so you can't put generics on generics. You can wrap the monad type behind a common API however, and that's what AnyM does.

If anyone is interested the cyclops-monad-api now has a growing range of [Monad Transformers](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/wiki/cyclops-monad-api-:-Monad-Transformer-OptionalT-overview-and-examples), inspired by this question - thanks OP!

Answer (score 0):

There is a project https://github.com/DanielGronau/highj on github, which tries to overcome java's lack of higher kinded types.

But you could also spare your sweat and use a functional programming language with proper higher kinded types, like https://github.com/Frege/frege